# Calling Javascript function from Client template in Kendo Grid MVC

Tags: kendo-grid

We are using Kendo Grid MVC and JQuery. Am calling Javascript function inside a ClientTemplate in Kendogrid and it works fine with Chrome, however in IE it gives an error message 'Invalid character', and when I debugged I found

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0rgx.png)

[JS Function error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eNTM.png)

It seems to be a syntax error. Could anyone help me on this issue

Comment: I guess it is the grave accent IE does not like. Replace every `\`` with an escaped double or single quote and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, I did try with single quote and double quote, but still some syntax errors are there. Am little bit confused with the syntax for passing parameters with function inside a client template.

Comment: Please post your updated code (simply edit your original post). Did you keep in mind to escape the (single) quote? Something like that should work: `loadAddComment(\'#:RoNumber#\'...`